# How do I make sure my sample size is sufficient for regression analysis?

Tags: regression

I have looked at 300 patients receiving two different types of treatment and I want to run a linear regression first and then a multiple regression on a variety of variables to see if any of these variables have an impact in complication rates for these two treatments. However I now find that only 2 patients have complications given treatment B, but sample size B is also significantly smaller than treatment A.

How do I know if these numbers are too low to run a regression on?

Comment: When you run the regression and get insignificant results, one possible conclusion is the sample size is too small.  Have you gone through this process yet?

Comment: So if P is significant, sample size should be adequate?

Comment: *So if P is significant, sample size should be adequate?*

A major worry of low sample size is "underpowered"--when there is truly a difference, but we ended up failed to reject the null hypothesis (no difference) because we don't have enough observations. So, if we tried the test and it's significant, we'd know that the "missing the chance to reject the null that should be rejected" (known as type II error) is not a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Out of all standard techniques in statistics, ordinary linear regression is one of the best suited for small samples. In general, it can be used with no issues if the sample size is at least equal to the number of features. And even when the sample size is less than the number of features, you can use penalized linear regression. So, there's no doubt you can use linear regression.

Of course, it's still the case that the smaller your sample, the less accurate your estimates, the wider your confidence intervals, and the less powerful your significance tests.

Comment: But with a binomial outcome variable (treatment 0 or treatment 1) I must use logistic regression right?

Comment: @Paze Logistic regression isn't the only option for binary outcomes, but it's often a good one.

Comment: But can I run an ordinary linear regression with a binary outcome?

Comment: @Paze You can, but it's rarely a good idea, because the assumptions of additive effects and normally distributed error are clearly wrong. Logistic regression is a better choice. Unfortunately, logistic regression also makes small samples more troublesome because of e.g. complete separation. You may want to ask a new question that provides more detail about the data and assesses separation issues.